# How to fix First Character Only bug

Tags: reactjs, go, axios, react-table

I am facing a complex bug where two json fields, the name and the description, only show their first character on a table every now and then randomly for no apparent reason. Has anyone ran into this issue? Attached screenshots of behavior below.

My web stack consists of a golang api get request being called using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) by a react frontend where I feed a [react table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) component.

[Table with first character only bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORQxS.png)

[Table with expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7NOz.png)

Axios Call

```
fetchMaintenanceEventsData() {
        let parent = this;
        console.log('Fetching Maintenance Events Data');
        this.setState({
            maintenanceEventsData: [],
            maintenanceEventsDataLoading: true
        });
        axios.get(`server-status/events`)
            .then((res) => {
                // console.log('res.data: ', res.data);
                parent.setState({
                    maintenanceEventsData: res.data,
                    maintenanceEventsDataLoading: false
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error:", error);
                parent.setState({
                    maintenanceEventsDataLoading: false
                })
            });
    }
```

I expect the table fields to display completely 100% of the time.

Comment: Before we jump to any conclusions that this is caused by react or react-table, try to log the response you are getting from your axios request and see if it matches your expectations.

Comment: Could be an api issue, like @DayColor said, if that's eliminated, then we can look at the front-end code to debug it.

Comment: In the screenshots I have the console printing the json object that feeds the table. I am printing this from a child component though. I will edit the post to attach a screenshot of the api call response which takes place on a parent component just need to wait until I get the bug displaying again which usually takes a couple minutes.

Comment: The issue really could be anywhere on the stack I am not sure where the bug is but I have been using postman and so far I don't get the bug using postman. I can post my go handler code but its almost 150 lines long.

Comment: I agree the bug could be anywhere, my method to resolve it is first ensure the backend is consistently and reliably returning accurate data. That way it eliminates that part of my code from the bug, and then I can focus on the frontend. 
What you have here is just the frontend and it's impossible to say for sure that this is where the bug is. 
I'd recommend create a code sandbox and atleast find a way to reproduce the bug