# Go API microservice occasionally returns first character in a string or garbage characters. Is there a known error that may cause this?

Tags: python, reactjs, go, gorilla, kong

I have a few API microservices that use gorrilla mux/handlers that randomly return characters that are not in the string, or only the first character. The problem never shows up when tested in Postman, about 10% of the time when called from the React.js front end, 50% of the time when called from AWS lambda python function when called every minute, and nearly never when lambda is called once every 3 minutes. To be honest, I am not sure where in the stack this is going wrong.

The microservices are running in a docker container within an OpenShift cluster that are ran though a Kong API gateway. Currently I am leaning to the problem being within gorrilla mux/handlers or the GoLang code, because we had the same issue before we moved to OpenShift and it seems to be happening across a few different clients, and services.

First, we looked into the problem being in the frontend. This is where we notice the first character only bug. We thought this may be an issue with react possibly displaying the data before it pulls all of it. So we logged the object that was returned and it contains the same data. What is interesting is that most of the strings are fine except one that is usually >100 characters, and when it happens it happens to all of strings with the same key. Again this only happens about 5-10% of the time and refreshing normally fixes it.

Then we noticed that an AWS lambda python function was getting garbage data from a similar API service. Sometimes '\000000\0000000' over and over again, or random parts of other strings from the JSON output, would be added in the middle of other strings. This started happening more often (as more data was added to the DB tables) until it was about 50% of the time when the lambda function was called every minute. I changed the call to be scheduled every three minutes and the problem disappeared.

When I go to find where in the stack this is happening with postman calls the problem never shows up, even when I blast calls in rapid succession. Which makes this a bit of a pain to track down.

I am not certain that the problems between lambda and the react front end are the same but I figured that the inconsistency is what is consistent between these problems. I am chalking up the difference in how this inconsistency is expressed to how the JSON is read into the clients.

I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction on this. Google and GitHub are not returning any known bugs that seem similar, and I am at a bit of a loss on where to be probing this one.

Comment: Somebody [asked a similar question a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332313/how-to-fix-first-character-only-bug).  When you test with PostMan, are you testing the same service instances used by the react frontend and the lambda function?

Comment: Yea, both of us are working on the same problem it just got passed along to me. No they are different services but they are built on the same template. They do pass along the same fields from the DB however.

Comment: When you test with PostMan, are you testing the same service instances used by the react frontend and the lambda function?  Does the response from the service include data read from the request body?

Comment: React and the lambda function use different services, but when I test with PostMan I test the same instances respectively. No there is no data in the request body in either instance.